# How to open another folder in VSCode in the same instance?

Tags: windows, macos, terminal, visual-studio-code

Let's say I have 2 folders - **apple** & **orange**

Now I opened **apple** in VSCode using `code apple`.

In the embedded terminal in VSCode, how do I open **orange** folder in the same instance as **apple** by overriding it without starting a new instance?

Answer (score 9):

Support for multi-root workspaces is there.vscode-insiders which support multiple projects at same time.Please refer to our [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces) for a full explanation of all the features that come with it. Extension authors should refer to our wiki that explains the new extension APIs to make your extension ready for multi-root workspaces.

### You can do it like this:

I just tried in my system it working perfectly fine to ***open a another folder in same instance***

```
code -r path
```

**Like:** `code -r C:\Users\admin\xxxx\xxxx\apple`(orange already opened in the same instance)

**If you want to** ***open a existing folder in new window from terminal:***

`code -n Path`

**Like:** `code -n C:\Users\admin\xxxx\xxxx\apple`(apple will opens in another window and orange also there.)

**If you want to** ***open a new tab in same instance by terminal:***

`code filename.extension` (Hit enter then just press `ctrl+S` and then it saved the file in the same directory).

Thanks for the question.Hope this will match your curiosity B|

Comment: oops i'm sorry. i couldn't decide between workspace & instance so i wrote workspace. i now know both mean different things. i edited the question to reflect that. can u answer again?

Comment: If you want to open simply new project or folder in the same instance then all you need to do: Go to FILE>OPEN FOLDER or (Ctrl+K+O).Please let me know if you asking this or I'm getting wrong

Comment: No, I want to open it from the command line. Like I do, `code .` from the folder I want to open. Similarly, I want to do something like `code apple/ -something`. `-something` is some parameter which opens the `apple/` folder in the same instance. I hope u understood now :)

Comment: I understand but i don't understand why you want to do like that because you can able to do that by going FILE>OPEN FOLDER or (Ctrl+K+O).So, it's just a curiosity or it's your need.

Comment: just curiosity, not a need. honestly, I open too many VSCode instances many times when I'm coding so I have to open one using VSCode's terminal & close that same instance & then check the new one. Instead, I'd love to open it into the same instance. But it's not that much of a problem. It probably takes me 30 seconds 

Comment: if you give code -n path or code path. that will also open but not in the same instance.I also tried but not able to found anything significant as workaround.

Comment: i've seen it a couple weeks ago somewhere `-r` or `-n` idk which but i couldn't find it so i asked it :)

Comment: I just modified my answer,i think this will work for you now

Comment: naah doesn't work in Mac. I'm sure on Windows it must be working. If I add `-r` or `-n` at the end, then it ignores them & opens a new instance anyway. I think it should be a Mac only feature :)

Comment: see [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14847#issuecomment-257847659) it's for mac

Comment: i want to open folders not files. anyways i tried it & it doesn't work. trust me tried the same thing 10 times before even asking the question. thanks for the help tho :)

Answer (score 1):

@rioV8 suggested [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70989223/open-2-folders-in-vscode) solution: File > Add Folder to Workspace ==> Multi Root Workspace