# Open 2 folders in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it true that we cannot open two folders simultaneously on VS Code ?

As per my observation suppose I have two folder namely f1 and f2.
When I open f1 and then if I want to open f2 then it automatically closes folder f1.

So, is this problem can be fixed ? or is it default in VS code ?

Comment: Run 2 instances of VS Code. One with F1 and the other with F2.

Comment: **File** > **Add Folder to Workspace**  ==> Multi Root Workspace